# How do I solve this differential equation through separation of variables?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> The motion of an object is can be defined in this formula $$ F = mg - kv^2 = ma$$ where $F$ is force, $m$ is the mass, $a$ is acceleration, $g$ is gravitational force and $k$ is air resistance. Solve for $v$.

---

Firstly, Acceleration: $a = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{dv}{dt}$, Therefore, $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$

$F = ma = m (\frac{d^2x}{dx^2})  = mg - k (\frac{dx}{dt})^2$

$m(\frac{dv}{dt}) = mg - kv^2$

I've made a second order differential equation into first order so I can solvethis using separation of variables which is used for first order differential equation. In class, the teacher said that I should divide $ (mg - kv^2)$ on both sides. Why is this the case and what does that do?

I separated the variables:

$m (dv) = dt (mg-kv^2)$

Divide $ (mg - kv^2)$ on both sides and made $dv$ the subject

$$\int \frac{1}{mg-kv^2} dv = \int {1}{m} dt = \frac{t}{m} + C$$

How do I solve the left hand side integral to get the following?

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}} \tanh \left(\sqrt{\frac{gk}{m}} (t)\right)$$

I understand that $m,g,k$ are just "numerical values" so it is similar to the integration of lets say $$\int \frac{1}{1-v^2} dv = \tanh^{-1} v + C$$ but because there are so many unknown values, I am not sure how to solve it properly

Comment: Gravitational force??

Comment: Just to have an alternative way to the solution, consider $y=e^{kx/m}$, then $\ddot y=\frac{k}{m^2} (m\ddot x+k\dot x^2)y=\frac{kg}{m}y$ has an easy solution as linear DE via exponentials.

Comment: Say"untanglel" or "disentangle" the variables for a system of ordinary differential equations. "separation of variables" is something else entirely.

Comment: @P.Lawrence Proper or not, I've heard seen the term "separation of variables" used for this ODE technique by many professors and textbooks.

Comment: OP, are you familiar with integration by u-substitution? That's the only piece you're missing here. (Equivalent to Sine of the Time's answer, but perhaps more intuitive for you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We begin from the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
m\dfrac{dv}{dt}=mg-kv^2 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dv}{mg-kv^2}=\dfrac{dt}{m}
\end{equation}
Integrating both sides and assuming $t_0=0$ and $v_0=0$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{v}\dfrac{dv}{mg-kv^2}=\int_0^{t}\dfrac{dt}{m}
\end{equation}
Now we consider the left hand side integral:
\begin{equation}
\int\dfrac{dv}{mg-kv^2}=\dfrac{1}{mg}\int\dfrac{dv}{1-\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{mg}}\,v\right)^2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{mg}{k}} \dfrac{1}{mg}\int\sqrt{\frac{k}{mg}}\dfrac{dv}{1-\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{mg}}\,v\right)^2}
\end{equation}
The last integral is equal to :
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\dfrac{mg}{k}} \dfrac{1}{mg}\int\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{mg}}\dfrac{dv}{1-\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{mg}}\,v\right)^2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{mgk}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{mg}}v\right)+c
\end{equation}
Evaluating the 2 integrals we obtain:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{mgk}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{mg}}v\right)=\dfrac{t}{m}
\end{equation}
From the last we easily have:
\begin{equation}
v(t)=\sqrt{\dfrac{mg}{k}}\,\tanh\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{gk}{m}}\,t\right)
\end{equation}