# Integrate $\int_0^v \frac{m}{mg - kv^2} dv$

Tags: integration

> Integrate $\displaystyle{\int_0^v \frac{m}{mg - kv^2}} dv$

First, I pull out the constants.

$\displaystyle{\int_0^v \frac{m}{mg} \frac{1}{1- \frac{k}{mg} v^2} dv = \frac{1}{g} \int_0^v \frac{1}{1- \frac{k}{mg} v^2}dv}$

$\displaystyle{\dfrac{1}{g} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{k/mg}} \tanh^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{mg}} v\right)\right]_0^v}$

According to the answer key I have, how do I get $\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{gk}}$ from $\dfrac{1}{g} \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k/mg}}\right)$

Comment: What is your question? Isn't $$\sqrt{\frac{m}{gk}}=\frac{1}{g} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k/mg}}\right)?$$

Comment: Write $g$ as $\sqrt{g^2}$ and combine the square roots.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4574838/1118406

Answer (score 1):

Following up from @Benjamin Wang, I think what you have here is the correct answer! Namely
$$\frac{1}{g}\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}\arctan\left( \sqrt{\frac{k}{mg}}v \right)=\sqrt{\frac{m}{gk}}\arctan\left( \sqrt{\frac{k}{mg}}v \right)$$
since the $g$ gets cancelled with the numerator. I hope that this answers your question!